# What is the relation among Prakriti, Maya, the law of Karma?

Tags: scripture, vedas

I'd like to know whether the following explanations right or not?
1.Prakriti is the matter consisted of 24 elements.  Is that right?
2.There are many kind of energy in this world,like heat energy, potential energy, sound energy and electric energy,etc. But these energy are changing to another energy. The scientists do not know what the energy is. I think these energy are Maya. Is that right?
3.So,Maya is the energy to make Prakriti to move.For example, smartphone is made of material elements. And the energy, Maya, makes smartphone to activate. Is that right?
4. The same way Maya makes Prakriti to activate and make us to believe that this world,Prakriti,is the real. Is that right?
5.Maya is also the principle of cause and effect, causality, the law of Karma. Is that right?

Comment: 1.- Prakriti = buddhi, ahankaar, 5 tanmatra, manas, 5 gyanendriya, 5 karmendriya = 23 and prakriti (the three gunas) = 24. 2. Maya and Prakriti are somewhat same(someone please correct me). Prakriti itself is shakti i.e. energy. Prakriti is jada in nature that is cannot move itself there has to be someone to drive it i.e. purusha or the chetana tattva (Brahma). He is the shaktiman and it is because of him Prakriti can move. That is to say when Prakriti and Purusha combine then prakriti can move. Someone can please correct my above statements.

Comment: on impartan you have rightly nailed the its brahman which makes all this tattvas operate but for whom? here we need 25 concept that is jiva , 26 lakshmi and 27 is narayana

Comment: The Answer is Jiva is the relation.. all this is done for Jiva.. that is the relationship one can derive

Comment: 5T+5GI+5KI+5 bhoota and manas buddhi ahamkara chita or mahat tatva (Shrada or belief system) 17+7 24 @Archit

Comment: Dear Prasanna R, thank you for your answer.  I'll have to take that into consideration．

Comment: @PrasannaR . aren’t Bhagwan Vishnu and Lakshmiji not separate from these tattvas? Isn’t the full world be it jada chetana Narayana? How can we name them as separate tattvas? 2. Also I thought mahat and buddhi are same. What’s the difference between manas, buddhi vs chitta?

Comment: @Prasanna R wait sorry I didn’t exactly catch what you’re saying. Are you saying that Jiva is separate from Hari? Or jiva is karta?

Comment: Just like a car is made of wheels, engine, seat, metal body, but is useless and still without a driver, similarly 24 elements of Prakriti make a body, its driver is the Purusha or soul and is the main difference between an alive and dead person. Just like one can buy quality car based on personal wealth, similarly one gets body suit and ambiance based on past births accumulated karmas and processed by Prakriti or Maya or Shakti(energy) or divine feminine.

Comment: Dear Manu Kumar, thank you for your teaching. Yes, that is right. Without driver, soul, the car itself can not move. I just make sure, the relation between the machine and energy. I think my expression does not work. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Manas makes the desire buddhi decide good or bad Chittaa memory shell from which earlier desire and outcome stored suppose let's take additctin example first time person takes alcohol manas desired but buddhi told it's bad Chita what is already stored helps the buddhi to go for it  chitta is store house of karma now drinks second time there buddhi taken decision of yes no question after that buddhi stops working here mahat or belief system which puts one in the wrong company @Archt